# How do I prevent this pop-up from appearing in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[Pop-up in VSC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fO7yE.jpg)

I really don't like it.

Comment: search settings for `TypeHints`, later on you will want to enable it again

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I searched for that in the settings page, but there are 6 options. Also, the way to enable or disable them is not clearly given. Regards from Peer.

Comment: 6 options is a lot better than the 300+ options you start with